# WP7 - RootFrame = new TransitionFrame(); - MissingMethodException

Tags: windows-phone-7, exception, transition

I am getting the following error when trying to debbug my application using Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone:

MissingMethodException was unhandled

Method not found: BackKeyPress osoft.Phone, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral ...

I am trying to add the line RootFrame = new TransitionFrame(); on the app.xaml.cs following the sample http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Navigation-Transitions-Step-By-Step-guide

Please someone has been through it before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you are somehow using mismatching versions of the toolkit and your app targetting?

Make sure your app and the toolkit both target the same OS version (7.1 or 7.0).

Comment: Yeah! Right on the spot... I download the previous version and now it's working. Thank you so much.

Comment: Cool. Though, I don't see how you'd be getting this error when using the old toolkit on the new platform (which is what I am assuming you are doing)... Weird. Glad it worked out.